# woocommerce shortcode add to extra fee

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I want ask a questions. I need help about this subject.

There are a code on woocommerce [product-id=50] I want show customers 3-6-9 month.

Hire-purchase on the table.

Cash price 100 $ [product-id=50] it s gonna looking 100 $ show up 100 $

-3 hire purchase %10 [product-id=50+%10] show up 110 $

-6 hire purchase %12 [product-id=50+%12] show up  120 $

Extra fee shortcode table functions. i dont know.

Comment: I need a little more elaboration on what it is you need. Do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: screenshots.
1- my print page : [link](http://prntscr.com/5mdxmm)
1- my admin page : [link](http://prntscr.com/5mdy99)

my shortcode [add_to_cart id='xxxx'] this print 100$ so.